# How to pass value to Angular app from iframe

Tags: angular, iframe

I have Angular 9 app with routes.

It's embedder into ASP.NET app in iframe (I don't have control over this setup, Angular's `/dist` folder is inside ASP.NET app's folder structure).

Everything works fine, but the new requirement is to load explicit route by default.

Here's the current setup:

```
<iframe src="[path]/index.html" />
```

Looking for something like below (which blows up with `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.html'`)

```
<iframe src="[path]/index.html?r=whatever" />
```

**Question:** How do I pass a value to angular from its parent iframe? (`index.html` has to be in the `src`, and that seems to be the main problem on the Angular side)

Answer (score 0):

You can send events to the iframe and react to these in the angular app.

[MDN postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)